# Why does not work method of deleting items by name?

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

The method of removing products by their name does not work. I'm trying to delete using `buttDelete.addEventListener` but the deletion does not happen.

The logic of the `deleteProductByName` method is that when the name of product is received from input `nameDelete` it is checked the same products in `shop.products` array, then when the button delete is press (`buttDelete`), the product is deleted from the array and correspondingly from the table too, if the field is empty, then output alert that you need to fill out the field.

Help please fix that

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
// Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor() {
        this.products = [];
    }

    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }

    //method for remove product by name
    deleteProductByName(productName) {
        let i = this.products.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (productName === this.products[i].name) {
                this.products.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    // get total price by all products
    get totalProductsPrice() {
        return this.products.map(product => product.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
    }

    // method to draw the table with product property (
    // name, count, price)
    show() {
        const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shop .data");
        for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            const e = rows.item(i);
            e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
        }
        const table = document.getElementById("shop");
        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            //create table
            table.innerHTML += `<tbody><tr class="data"><td>${this.products[i].name}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].price}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].count}</td></tr></tbody>`;
        }
        //show total price by all products
        table.innerHTML += `<tfoot><tr id="total-price"><td colspan="3">Total price: 
        ${shop.totalProductsPrice}</td></tr></tfoot>`;
    }
}
// add new product by click
const formAdd = document.forms[0];
const inputsAdd = formAdd.elements;
const buttAdd = formAdd.elements[3];
buttAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    shop.addProduct(new Product(inputsAdd[0].value, parseInt(inputsAdd[2].value),
        parseInt(inputsAdd[1].value)));
    shop.show();
}, false);
// delete product by name after click
const formDelete = document.forms[1];
const nameDelete = formDelete.elements[0];
const buttDelete = formDelete.elements[1];
buttDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    shop.deleteProductByName(nameDelete.value);
    shop.show();
}, false);

let shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
shop.show();
```

```html
<div class="Shop">
    <div class="add-product">
        <h1>Add product</h1>
        <form id="addForm">
            <label for="name" >Name of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name" class="input-product">
            <label for="price">Price of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="price" class="input-product">
            <label for="count">Count of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="count" class="input-product">
            <button id="add">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
<div class="product-table">
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <form id="delete-form">
        <label for="name-delete">Delete product by name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name-delete" class="input-delete">
        <button id="delete" type="button">Delete</button>
    </form>
    <table id="shop">
        <caption>Products that are available in the store</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th id="filter">Price:</th>
            <th>Count:</th>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok but the problem is not this

Comment: Fix it at least in above example, please, because otherwise that’s rather pointless to begin with.

Comment: You need to append to the `<tbody>` of your `<table>`, not to the `<table>` directly. Look at the generated markup. It appears that each time you click the button, a new “Total price” is appended at the top. Is that the problem? Can’t see anything else.

Comment: Yes, really, thanks, did not notice this problem with a total price and unfortunately the addition of markup did not help :(

Comment: Could you tell us whether you getting correct productName into `deleteProductByName(productName) ` after click. And check the content of the array `this.products` after `deleteProductByName()` executed. That will separate problems of array manipulation from button delete not reacting to the click.
Because now it is not clear what is the problem.

Comment: The name does the right thing, but nothing happens with the array, its capacity does not change

Comment: You could use `filter` to create a new array Generally speaking mutating an array while iterating over it is considered to be a bad practice. `this.products = this.products.filter(product => product.name !== productName)`

Answer (score 1):

Then I would use a `console.log()` or a debugger on

```
   //method for remove product by name
   deleteProductByName(productName) {
       let i = this.products.length;
       while (i--) {
           console.log("productName " + productName + "this.products[i].name" + this.products[i].name);
           if (productName === this.products[i].name) {
               this.products.splice(i, 1);
           }
       }
   }
```

to see if you comparing the same names. To make sure your if statement is working as expected.

Comment: i add  e.preventDefault(); first in  buttDelete.addEventListener and removing products by name is working.

Comment: Can you tell me how to solve the problem of the appearance of a new line the total price  after click on the delete or add item button?

Comment: @IgorShvets product is getting deleted properly from the memory. The presentation part has issues. Ur markup is not correct. open the `tbody` before the loop and close it after the loop, not inside

Comment: @Nithin Chandran you mean put before the for "table.innerHTML =` <tbody> ;" and after the for "table.innerHTML = </ tbody> `;" ?